# Transactions and Rollback for Typed DataSets in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, dataset

How do I include the typed dataset in my transaction so that I can rollback when I catch an error? Is there a way where I can commit both the typed and untyped dataset?

```
          myTransaction = calConnect.Connection.BeginTransaction("myRollback")

         Try
            CommandInsertCE.Transaction = myTransaction

            CommandInsertCE.ExecuteNonQuery()
            myTransaction.Commit()

            dgvwCalibRes.DataSource = CalibrationDataSet.Tables("CalibrationTrials")
            taCalTrials.Update(Me.CalibrationDataSet.CalibrationTrials)

        Catch ex As Exception
            myTransaction.Rollback("myRollback")

        End Try
```